# changing the numbering of several files

Tags: shell-script, files

I have 456 files with the format like

```
aaa_0.plt
aaa_2.plt
...
aaa_455.plt
```

I want to change them so that the numbers starts from 910 and I would have

```
aaa_910.plt
...
aaa_1365.plt
```

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(aaa_)(<0-455>)(.plt)' '$1$(($2+910))$3'
```

Comment: That is true codegolf !

Answer (score 2):

try

```
seq 0 455 | while read a
do
    b=$(($a + 910))
    echo mv aaa_$a.plt aaa_$b.plt 
done
```

for a preview

then

```
 ...
 done | bash
```

to run